# Issues with using indexBy in OneToMany when specifying a field from the associated ManyToOne

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm facing an issue while using the OneToMany annotation in Doctrine ORM. I have entities `Product`, `ProductAttribute`, and `Attribute`. The `ProductAttribute` entity has a `ManyToOne` relationship with the `Attribute` entity.

Here is an example of the code:

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: 'Catalog\Attribute')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'attribute_uuid', referencedColumnName: 'uuid')]
protected Attribute $attribute;

#[ORM\OneToMany(
    targetEntity: 'Catalog\ProductAttribute',
    mappedBy: 'product',
    indexBy: 'attribute.address'
)]
protected $productAttributes;
```

When I try to use `indexBy` with the field `attribute.address` in the `OneToMany` annotation, it doesn't work as expected. The query is executed, but indexing does not occur, and the array remains ordinary.

Are there any limitations or peculiarities when using indexBy in `OneToMany` with fields from associated ManyToOne entities? Has anyone encountered a similar issue and can provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**What did you try and what were you expecting?**

I attempted to use the `indexBy` attribute in the OneToMany annotation, specifying the field `attribute.address` to index the resulting array by the `address` property of the associated `Attribute` entity. However, despite executing the query successfully, the indexing did not take place, and the array remained unindexed.

I expected that using `indexBy` with a field from the associated ManyToOne entity would result in an array indexed by the specified field, allowing me to access `ProductAttribute` entities using the `address` property of the associated `Attribute`.

If there are any specific steps or configurations needed to achieve this, I'd appreciate guidance on how to correctly utilize `indexBy` in this scenario.